# Выбрать из одной таблице строку если соответствует условию во второй таблице. Как?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы table1 и table2 ... в них есть разные строк. В table1 "user_deistvie" и "metka_deistviya". В table2 "user_name" и "user_deistvie" и "date" ...

Они заполнены. user_deistvie может быть одинаковые в двух таблицах, а могут быть пустыми, а так же могут отсутствовать. Дата в table2 записывается в будущем времени.

Мне необходимо выбрать из таблицы 1 user_deistvie, при условии что сегодняшняя дата(подставляю сегодняшнюю из php, $date) больше чем в таблице 2(то есть не через неделю а уже прошла), при условии что такая строка вообще есть и что metka_deistviya из первой таблице "55"(к примеру).

Как такой мега запрос оформить? Подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: Обычный JOIN по коду действия плюс все остальные условия отбора во WHERE... Кстати, MySQL прекрасно сам может подставить дату в запрос - у него тоже есть подходящая функция.

Comment: хм .. а что это за функция?

Comment: *что это за функция?* [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) и её синонимы CURRENT_DATE и CURRENT_DATE().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user_deistvie 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.user_deistvie = t2.user_deistvie
WHERE '2019-09-09' > t2.date AND t1.metka_deistviya = '1'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8df9/1

Comment: Так же нужно чтобы из table1 бралось действие тоже .. тут получается только анализирует вторую таблицу .. а так работает конечно на ура. Если например из вашего примера то если добавить в первую таблицу ('test table', '1'), то оно не выведет, а нужно чтобы тоже выводило. Спасибо

Comment: А из второй таблицы выводило только если дата соответствует. Тут верно срабатывает код

Comment: если в первой таблице будет действие 'test table', а во второй не будет, то это действие не выведется. Нужно чтобы выводилось? Это вроде как противоречит изначальной постановке вопроса: `выбрать из таблицы 1 user_deistvie, при условии что такая строка вообще есть и что metka_deistviya из первой таблице "55"`. Потому что как к записи из `t1` в таком случае привязать дату из `t2`?

Comment: По вашим комментариям будто бы вам нужно чтобы выводилось либо просто действие из первой таблицы с меткой (в случае если во второй такого действия нет), либо, если действие есть и в первой и во второй  таблице, то нужно ещё на время смотреть? В случае, если действие будет только во второй, метку к нему привязать не получится.